# What's better? Scoped searches in models or in helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best practice for scoped search that will end up in the view (i.e. current_company_name)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None, you should use decorators or presenters.

Useful Railscast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper).

Comment: Nice!  I currently use the `||=` operator in controllers / helpers for data that's frequently used in the view to avoid making unnecessary calls back for data if the variable states haven't changed.  Can decorators support that?

Answer (score 0):

I think in helpers, because `current_company_name` is related to current application state, not to data.